# Is it possible to integrate SVN with OpenERP?

Tags: svn, odoo

Instead of doing check-in of files in SVN manually, I want to integrate SVN with OpenERP so that I can upload files directly from OpenERP screen to SVN.
Any experts in OpenERP give me some idea if it is possible.

Comment: Try to search the some plugin for ooDo, or write it by yourself with SVN-Python binding http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.developer.usingapi.html#svn.developer.usingapi.otherlangs.ex-1

Comment: Thank you @Y.N So you are mean to say that if we have a plug-in for that, then it becomes possible right?

Comment: If oodo store the files in plain form, not in database - then I think yes.

Comment: Great thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer these links below.
what I need is given here.
http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html
http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_guide.html